# Should `isinstance()` check against typing or collections.abc?

Tags: python, isinstance

Both `typing` and `collections.abc` includes similar type such as `Mapping`, `Sequence`, etc.

Based on the python documentation, it seems that `collections.abc` is preferred for type checking:

> This module provides abstract base classes that can be used to test whether a class provides a particular interface; for example, whether it is hashable or whether it is a mapping.
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html

but using `typing` also works and I'd rather not import `Mapping` from both `typing` and `collections.abc`. So is there any catch in using `typing` with `isinstance()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many of the `typing` generic classes are just aliases to the `abc` ones. Just as an example from the docs, [Hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Hashable):

> class typing.Hashable
>
> An alias to collections.abc.Hashable

Also,

```
isinstance(abc.Hashable, typing.Hashable)
isinstance(typing.Hashable, abc.Hashable)
```

are both True, making it clear they are equivalent in terms of the class hierarchy. In Python you can check an alias's origin using the origin field:

```
>>> typing.Hashable.__origin__
<class 'collections.abc.Hashable'>
```

No reason I can see to import `abc` if you do not need it. The two packages provide close but different uses, so I would import only what you need. This is more of an opinion, but if your use-case is only checking against `isinstance` (i.e. no interesting argument annotation) both seem equivalent to me, though `abc` may be the more usual tool for this.

Answer (score 8):

As of python 3.9, the entire suite of `collections.abc` aliases in the `typing` module [is deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#abstract-base-classes), meaning that your preferred option for python >=3.9 should be to use the versions in the `collections.abc` module. The classes [will not be removed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/#implementation) from the `typing` module for a few years to come, however.

Answer (score 4):

There is no catch. The `typing` library uses stubs from the `collections` library. You are totally allowed to use `isinstance` with the typing library, certainly for the types you mentioned (Mapping and Sequence).